# Casting Spells at close range as a Cleric

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, cleric

If I'm within 5 feet of an enemy, is my character still able to cast **[Sacred Flame](http://ephe.github.io/grimoire/spells/sacred-flame/)** on him or do I get disadvantage due to it being a ranged spell and not a touched based one?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> Aiming a ranged attack is more difficult when a foe is next to you. When you make a ranged attack with a weapon, a spell, or some other means, you have **disadvantage on the attack roll** if you are within 5 feet of a hostile creature who can see you and who isn’t incapacitated.

Reading the text for Sacred Flame, it does not require an attack roll, just a saving throw from the  target.

> Flame-like radiance descends on a creature that you can 
>   see within range. **The target must succeed on a Dexterity 
>   saving throw** or take 1d8 radiant damage. The target 
>   gains no benefit from cover for this saving throw.

Since you are not making an attack roll, you do not have disadvantage.

Answer (score -4):

from the Basic Rules, p73:

> Aiming a ranged attack is more difficult when a foe is next to you. When you make a ranged attack with a weapon, a **spell**, or some other means, **you have disadvantage on the attack roll if you are within 5 feet of a hostile creature** who can see you and who isn’t incapacitated.

Comment: This answer would apply well to Guiding Bolt, which requires an attack roll.  For a spell that doesn't have the character of "ranged attack" which is what this paragraph addresses, it doesn't.